# Using the WebBrowser control to load several HTML files from disk

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webbrowser-control

I am trying to display HTML files (containing local images) in a `WebBrowser` control. User can select the file using an `OpenFileDialog`, after which it is displayed in the control.

But I have these problems I am struggling to solve:

1. Since I've added the control to my `Form`, it's been loading really slowly. It takes almost 10s for the form to instantiate.
2. `WebBrowser.Navigate` only works the first time. When I try to load the second file, nothing happens. I have tried calling `Refresh`, `Update`, `OpenNew`, opening `about:blank` between two files, but I just don't have a clue how to do it properly. Only the initially opened file remains shown, no exceptions or warnings ever pop up when I try to navigate to a different page.

Am I doing something wrong? For example, [Lutz Roeder's Writer](http://www.lutzroeder.com/dotnet/#writer) starts instantly and loads subsequent files without problems, but it uses lots of interop (and is editable), so I am trying to avoid all that stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I have been loading local `.html` files into a `WebBrowser` is like so:

```
OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
// Do filtering here
if (ofd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
{
    webBrowser1.DocumentText = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(ofd.FileName);
}
```

It can load files one after another with no problems. If you are trying to load a big html file when the form is initializing or is opening this could explain the 10 second loading time. My form loaded almost instantly when it had a `WebBrowser` control on it.

Hope this helps!

**Edit:** Try setting the stream of the `WebBrowser`:

```
System.IO.Stream s = System.IO.File.OpenRead(ofd.FileName);
webBrowser1.DocumentStream = s;
```

Comment: Thanks. Well, the problem with setting `DocumentText` is that images then don't get displayed, since they usually have relative paths. This is why I try to load through the `Uri` property. And yes, I've just created a test project and it start immediately, but my old one takes ages to load (and it's not opening anything).